# Jquery template generated HTML coming outside the tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

```
<ul class="messagesList ifClicked">
           <script id="questionsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">  
                   <li>
                      <span class="from">${source} </span>
                   </li>
             </script>
</ul>
```

I have the above jquery template code.
The expected output by me is like

```
<ul class="messagesList ifClicked">
                   <li>
                      <span class="from">Reuters</span>
                   </li>                   
                   <li>
                      <span class="from">CNN</span>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                      <span class="from">CNN</span>
                   </li>
</ul>
```

But what is coming is  (While looking in firebug)

```
<ul class="messagesList ifClicked">
           <script id="questionsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">  
                   <li>
                      <span class="from">${source} </span>
                   </li>
             </script>
</ul>
                       <li>
                          <span class="from">Reuters</span>
                       </li>                   
                       <li>
                          <span class="from">CNN</span>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <span class="from">CNN</span>
                       </li>
```

What is the reason for the behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the template outside of ul list. That way you can simply empty the list if you want to reset it.

HTML:

```
<script id="questionsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">  
        <span class="from">${source} </span>
</script>

<ul class="messagesList ifClicked">

</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var list = [ 'Routers', 'CNN', 'CNN' ];

    var tmpl = '';
    $.each(list, function(num, el) {
        tmpl =  $('<li>').html($('#questionsTemplate').html());
        tmpl.find('.from').html(el);
        $('.messagesList').append(tmpl);
    });

});
```

[DEMO and CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/UVJRH/)

Comment: Hey , thanks @rokburgar - I did that test you gave me and found that  i appended the script to the wrong tag. Thanks a lot again.